# Ui-Router otherwise rule with ng-admin

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-admin

I have got a problem in an angular app, where I have integrated ng-admin to provide a simple admin panel. I have also integrated Authentication and want to point to a login state, when there is no current session.

Ng-admin itself sets ui-router's otherwise method to point directly to the dashboard.
Even when setting my own `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(...)` I am not able to force ui-router to use my otherwise function.

I tried it like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
    console.log('Hello World?!');
    state.go('login');
});
```

But the console.log is never printed...

I would like to intercept the state transition to the dashboard, before any dashboard-code is run, and redirect the user to the login page first.

Any hints and ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to use $on("stateChangeSuccess")

Comment: As I am setting the routing states in the configuration phase of angular, I am not sure where to put this...? Can I use this in an `angular.run(...)` block?

Comment: You can use it in your main module controller

Comment: The "main" controller lies in ng-admin, I have only controllers for specific states, which are not executed on first load of the application.

Comment: Can you try to use resolve function for specific states then you would be able to check session and change states?

Comment: For my own states I could easily add resolve, but I'm not sure how to do this for states defined in another module

Comment: can you add your main module to make question more clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148026/discussion-between-user8175473-and-minato).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @user8175473 for pointing me into the right direction.

I have solved the problem using `$on('$stateChangeStart)` as `$on('$stateChangeSuccess)` is called after some state code is executed.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    if(toState.name !== 'login' && !service.isLoggedIn()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

Note that `event.preventDefault()` is needed to cancel the state transition completely.